# gradle build Error:Execution failed for task ':core-app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, build-process

So it looks like I have a transitive dependency, which I can't resolve.
I have my core-app module which depends on another module(B), and another module(A) which also depends on B. Something like this:

```
core-app depends_on module_B

core-app depends_on module_A

module_A depends_on module_B
```

After searching I saw this solution: [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468700/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)
and tried this:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'my.package', module: ':module_B'
}
```

but I still have this ugly error when I try to run the app:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':core-app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/dex/debug 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/classes/debug 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-197cbd736ad01e53c31276271ae913486b0abf5b.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-3c3136b1a3d2e071fc0b25f37c5115244438cb45.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-6e775e8dcfd81b4448a33f89f29368ec66cde279.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-bd82247962e0da24f39e8f7dbf7adc766a7f8ea4.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-c5a1782afffa13143ca90626baf46256b7521223.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/comscore-501f7ccbcd2ef08a3b81c85e45538f5e5bb8db72.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/content-release-unsigned-5915579628ca7ffd706dfd83d8791a6900d71b88.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/core-0de7b51c98dd9c35c27949289c8a48ba50cde798.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/gcm-551b250131d562313127ab0d990e96fdc83abe51.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/HockeySDK-3.0.1-cffb40375ed4edee500e0b998409b63fe76a13f6.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/infonlinelib_private-58b4cfaa6af1eeaca7c757fb9828fac11d7c99eb.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/internal_impl-21.0.0-rc1-24afc028a4165dd5855f9a234d828ba29d5b9b2e.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jackson-core-2.2.3-03093703b9b63dae474edd11807c8fc1887274ab.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/library-1.2-5c388324ca54c5bd1f0edc8032aa1897feff9314.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/markdownview-1.2-303e1a11db64cd2119d013dc06e05520f8f1da36.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/picasso-2.1.1-2f0e493d5aefe82c2c095fb8a9c79a7d097af978.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2-69e9ce27885ad5e375621d00878eb8e692a5322d.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/signpost-core-1.2.1.2-f3438b2714532c18e609a09850c8541be9e1b0a5.jar 
>   /dev_workspace/android-app/core-app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-21.0.0-rc1-9da56907a54bc62b80b021d0066dc3e5625c73ba.jar
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lmy/package/Animations;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the problem. 
module_A was defined as an application (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`) after changing it to library (`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) it seems  to work. Which in my opinion is weird. If any of you has a better explanation don't hesitate to share it.