# Add a library from GitHub in Android Studio > 1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I would like to add [this library](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) from GitHub but it doesn't seem to be working when adding the following statement in the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
```

[image: Project tree]

I get the following error message:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
```

I read somewhere else that it had to do with the `support-v4` library. How could I resolve this?

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}}

 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
    compile files('libs/smartconfiglib.jar')
   // compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
 }
```

Comment: Have you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468700/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)? The answer there steps through an example resolution in a fair amount of detail.

Comment: Yes I have but I didn't understand what to do. Since I upgraded to ADT 1.0, my libs folder seeem to have disappeared from the project tree but yet it's seems to be still working.

Comment: Above the tree you have in your screenshot is a drop-down list. If that shows "Android", switch it to "Project", to get a filesystem look at your project contents.

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: Try removing `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'` from your depenceny? If you can a look at [their build.gradle](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/blob/master/datetimepicker-library/build.gradle), they have already compiled support v4 which now has conflict with your version.

Answer (score 0):

Your build file misses `repositories` block. [The dependency is in JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker%3Alibrary/view), so just add

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

That should do it.