# cordova plugins conflict on android platform

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

whenever i try to build my cordova app i got this error:

> :mergeArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :createXwalkCommandLineFileArmv7Debug
>   :generateArmv7DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :generateArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :mergeArmv7DebugResources
>   :processArmv7DebugManifest
>   :processArmv7DebugResources
>   :generateArmv7DebugSources
>   :compileArmv7DebugJava
>   :preDexArmv7Debug
>   :dexArmv7Debug
>
> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> :dexArmv7Debug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':dexArmv7Debug'.
>     com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>     /Users/sombriks/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/armv7/debug --input-list=/Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/armv7/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>     2
>     Output:
>
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 27.511 secs
>
> /Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^
>
> Error code 1 for command: /Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: /Users/sombriks/git/g4l-taxi/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
>
> at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
>
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
>
> [sombriks@eiko g4l-taxi]$

here comes my plugin list:

> [sombriks@eiko g4l-taxi]$ cordova plugin list
>
> cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.8.1 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
>
> cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
>
> cordova-plugin-extension 1.1.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
>
> cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.1 "Google Play Services for Android"
>
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
>
> org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"

Only the android build shows this issue, ios build compiles and runs.

some [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468700/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files) suggests to modify my build.gradle, but it had no effect so far.

If anyone had faced such problem before, please help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Creating a fresh project and adding just the [crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) gives me an working project, both android and ios. I'll add more plugins and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.1 "Google Play Services for Android"

Remove this plugin, it's deprecated and no more needed.

See FAQ 3: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/Difference-of-Plugin-IDs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone else runs on such kind of problem, here's my solution:

1. Back up your **www** folder
2. Update npm

   - *sudo yum update npm*
3. Update cordova

   - *sudo npm -g install cordova*
4. Create a brand new project

   - *codrova create MyFolder my.namespace "My Title"*
5. Bring your **www** folder back
6. Add all your plugins back:

   - *cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console*
   - *cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview*
   - *cordova-plugin-admobpro*
7. Add your platforms back:

   - *cordova platform add android*
   - *cordova platform add ios*

The issue is gone and seems to be related to the age of this project. I've faced one or two cordova versios update, no telling how much updates each plugin had.

In the end, keep the environment updated and clean could solve it.