# AndroidStudio build error complaining about JVM version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It seems to be looking for Java 7, but I am using Java 6 because if some earlier issues I had and needed to stick with Java 6.

Here is the screenshot so you can see the error message. How would I set the default JVM to 6 in AndroidStudio?

[image]

EDIT: actually I just changed it to Java 6, and I get the same error about Java 6 :( so maybe that wasn't the main cause of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need java 7 or above to run android studio (atleast on El Capitan). Looking at the TOP level exception error it could be due to this, [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468700/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)