# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION (react-native)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I got this error when I build my project, it's a react-native android project:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION : 
 com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Here is my gradle :

`apply from: "react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.movieproject"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {

    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
}`

I had install all the needed dependencies (google repository,...), delete the build folder but I always get this error.

If you have any links or tips, thanks ! And I canno't post a unique code, Stack overflow doesn't do it, grrrrr !

Comment: How does your build.gradle file look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468700/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

Comment: I think it's because I have a library declare twice... but witch, and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved ! Did some changes and after that `cd android/ && ./gradlew clean` fix it !

Comment: Thanks! Fixes the problem indeed.